# How to filter / validate for a boolean value?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate, zend-filter

i was just reading a great presentation about [Quality Assurance for PHP Projects](http://www.slideshare.net/DragonBe/workshop-quality-assurance-for-php-projects-tek12) by Michelangelo van Dam aka DragonBe. In his presentation he uses Zend-Framework as an example, which i am familiar with on a basic level.

Since i want to improve myself, im starting with unit testing, though i feel the problem is on ZFs side.

**The Problem:**

With given code-artifacts whenever i assign a boolean value of `false` the Zend_Filter or Zend_Validator changes this into `null`. I can't figure out why this is the case.

**Please see update on bottom for newer code and test**

**First the Tests**

```
public function goodData() {
  return array(
    array('DU-IT', 'Sample Description', true, false),
    array('Mercüß', 'bla"ß"trager', false, true),
    array('Mia123', '728 Tage im Jahr', false, false)
  );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider goodData()
 */
public function testModelAcceptsValidData($name, $description, $flag_active, $flag_deleted)
{
  $data = array(
    'id'            => 0,
    'name'          => $name,
    'description'   => $description,
    'flag_active'   => $flag_active,
    'flag_deleted'  => $flag_deleted
  );

  try {
    $this->_model->populate($data);
  } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    $this->fail('Unexpected Exception: '.$e->getMessage());
  }

  $this->assertSame($data, $this->_model->toArray());
}
```

**The Model**

```
public function __construct($props = null)
{
  // Set Filters
  $this->_filters = array(
    'id'            => array('Int'),
    'name'          => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
    'description'   => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
    'flag_active'   => array(new Zend_Filter_Boolean()),
    'flag_deleted'  => array(new Zend_Filter_Boolean())
  );

  // Set Validators
  $this->_validators = array(
    'id'            => array('Int'),
    'name'          => array(new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min'=>4, 'max'=>50))),
    'description'   => array(new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('max'=>5000))),
    'flag_active'   => array(new Zend_Validate_InArray(array(true, false))),
    'flag_deleted'  => array(new Zend_Validate_InArray(array(true, false)))
  );

  // Set Properties
  if (!is_null($props)) {
    $this->populate($props);
  }
}

public function setFlagActive($arg)
{
  $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($this->_filters, $this->_validators);
  $input->setData(array('flag_active'=>$arg));
  if (!$input->isValid('flag_active')) {
    throw new Zend_Exception('Invalid FLAG_ACTIVE provided'. gettype($input->flag_active));
  }
  $this->_flag_active = (bool) $input->flag_active;
  return $this;
}
```

As far as the model is concerned, i tried leaving the validator for `flag_active` and `flag_deleted` empty, but this did not change my results. The error message of phpunit remains the same:

```
Unexpected Exception: Invalid FLAG_ACTIVE providedNULL
```

Whereas NULL is the type of the variable, WHENEVER i pass `false` as the argument for the flag via the data-provider goodData() (same happens with badData, too).

My guess is this has something to do with Zend_Filter, but i just can't figure this out. And hints are greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Since Drew gave a little hint i've tested a little further, yet the problem remains. I have pasted the updated Class and unit test onto pastebin for better readability.

- [PasteBin of the Model Class](http://pastebin.com/A7QZqA6h)
- [PasteBin of the TestClass](http://pastebin.com/DsEzGwLH)

PHPUnit gives out the following error: `You must give a non-empty value for field 'flag_active'` same for flag_deleted. A second error on half the tests is `<null> does not match expected type "boolean"`. I'm stuck. No matter if i use filters or an inArrayValidator(array(0=>true,1=>false)) it doesn't change a thing :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine the contents of `$input->getMessages()`, it should provide some explanation as to why that particular value is coming through as invalid.

When you use `Zend_Filter_Input`, any value that did not pass validation will not be magically accessible by its name (e.g. `$input->flag_active`).  The value will always be `NULL` if it didn't pass the validation step.

Certain filters can almost guarantee validation in some cases (i.e. an Int filter with an Int validator) because the filter will filter the data and return a valid value for the validator.  Passing `hello` through the `Int` filter returns `0` which may validate with a simple `Int` validator even though the original input data is not valid.

The reason you are most likely getting a null value within your exception is because the value is not available since it didn't validate; therefore check the input messages for any hints as to why.

EDIT:

I think the problem you are having is that `Zend_Filter_Input` is not allowing empty values by default.  Therefore if the value coming into the filter is `false` or `NULL`, it is causing an error with the filter.

Check out this code:

```
    <?php

    // set up a boolean validator and inarray validator like you have
    $filters    = array('test' => array(new Zend_Filter_Boolean()));
    $validators = array('test' => array(new Zend_Validate_InArray(array(true, false))));

    // set up the input filter with default options
    $input      = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);

    // our "input" value which is (bool)false
    $test       = false;

    $input->setData(array('test' => $test));

    // run through input filter using default values
    // should throw error about a non-empty value
    if (!$input->isValid('test')) {
        echo "Test is not valid.  <br />Original Value: ";
        var_dump($test);
        echo "<br />";
        print_r($input->getMessages());
    } else {
        echo "Test is valid.<br />Original Value: ";
        var_dump($test);
        echo "<br />Value now: ";
        var_dump($input->test);
    }

    // now allowing empty values...
    echo "<hr />\n";

    // tell Zend_Filter_Input to allow empty values on input
    $options = array(Zend_Filter_Input::ALLOW_EMPTY => true);

    // set up new input filter with option
    $input   = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, null, $options);

    $input->setData(array('test' => $test));

    // run through input filter allowing empty values
    // this should NOT throw an error
    if (!$input->isValid('test')) {
        echo "Test is not valid.  <br />Original Value: ";
        var_dump($test);
        echo "<br />";
        print_r($input->getMessages());
    } else {
        echo "Test is valid.<br />Original Value: ";
        var_dump($test);
        echo "<br />Value now: ";
        var_dump($input->test);
    }
```

So the problem seems to be that Zend_Filter_Input doesn't like empty values unless you specify an option.  Therefore sending a valid (`false`) value into the filter causes an error unless you set `Zend_Filter_Input::ALLOW_EMPTY` to `true`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Sadly the known error message doesn't help out too much, as it's just a better written 'Hey, you got a null here' - see updated question for details with new class and test code. The question remains: **can boolean values be VALIDATED by Zend_Filter_Input** ? Even with empty filter/validator, as long as i input "false", the inputFilter fails badly, returning null.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$arg` coming into the set functions is what you expect?  I tested some things with `Zend_Filter_Input` and with a boolean filter, pretty much any value gets converted to bool for me so it's strange that this is failing.

Comment: There in fact was an error in the class that didn't set the attribute properly, but i managed to find it last 5 minutes of work. I will check further later - i didn't get it to work before that. May you be able to provide your example that worked with both true and false boolean value?

Comment: Here's a [paste](http://pastebin.com/rbiJS5fi) of what I used.  I'm going to update the answer in a moment with some helpful information I think.

Comment: Ok, it is good to know that there is an option, i will check this out in two days (sadly, only then). As far as i see it, empty value will allow for `NULL` to be assigned, too, right? I guess this can't be changed then. NULL would then have to be treated as FALSE, i guess i can live with that. Though it feels weird :)
Thanks upfront, i will let you know on thursday on how it went on my case and propperly assign the (little) award ;)

Comment: I tried that before and a `NULL` value will pass the filter and become a `false` value.  If that isn't desirable, you could check for null before you run it through zend_filter_input, but that's all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I just rebuilt this at home and it works as expected and explained by you. After some more research, this pretty much boils down to how PHP handles array with `false` as a boolean value. As in some cases it simply becomes `null`. No clue as to why that is, but this is pretty much the 'problem' i encountered here. So allowing nullable values will work out well enough for me :) THANK YOU